# Showing $E[(M_T-M_S)^2|\mathscr{F}_S]=E[M_T^2-M_S^2|\mathscr{F}_S]$ for Martingale $M_n$.

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

Let $(M_n)$ be a martingale with $M_n \in L^2$. $S,T$ are bounded stopping times w $S\leq T$. Show $M_T, M_T$ are both in $L^2$ and that

$E[(M_T-M_S)^2|\mathscr{F}_S]=E[M_T^2-M_S^2|\mathscr{F}_S]$

and that

$E[(M_T-M_S)^2]=E[M_T^2]-E[M_S^2]$

I believe I have shown the first equality, but I did not use $S \leq T$ or that M_T,M_S are in $L^2$, so I am concerned I made a mistake.  My proof is:

$E[(M_T-M_S)^2|\mathscr{F}_S]=E(M_T^2|\mathscr{F}_S] + E[M_S^2|\mathscr{F}_S] - 2E[M_TM_S|\mathscr{F}_S]$, and then since $M_S$ is $\mathscr{F}_S$ measurable, $E[M_TM_S|\mathscr{F}_S]=M_SE[M_T|\mathscr{F}_S]=M_S^2=E[M_S^2|\mathscr{F}_S]$, which then proves the desired equality.

The second equality, I expanded everything out, but don't see how to proceed from there.

Comment: The step $E[M_T|\mathscr{F}_S]=M_S$ very much uses the hypothesis that $S\leqslant T$ almost surely. To even consider $E(M_T^2|\mathscr{F}_S)$ and $E[M_S^2|\mathscr{F}_S]$, one needs to know that $M_T$ and $M_S$ are square integrable. // To prove the second identity, simply integrate the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your first equality,
\begin{align*}
E[(M_T - M_S)^2] &= E[E[(M_T - M_S)^2 | \mathcal{F}_S]] \\
&= E[E[M_T^2 - M_S^2|\mathcal{F}_S]] \\
&= E[M_T^2]-E[M_S^2].
\end{align*}
You should also mention the martingales are right-continuous so that we may apply optional stopping.

Comment: Thanks -- I'm not sure what you mean though about "optional stopping". I believe what you said works, as is without that comment? All of the martingales I'm dealing with are discrete, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I did not see the indexing was in $n$; I thought the martingales were in continuous time. About optional stopping: if $M_n$ is a martingale then we know $E[M_{n+1} | F_n] = M_n$ a.s. and so $E[M_m | F_n] = M_n$ for all $m \geq n$. It is not immediate that this holds for random times $T$ and $S$. The statement $E[M_T | F_S] = F_S$ a.s. for a.s. bounded stopping times with $S \leq T$ w.p.1, is part of the optional stopping (or sampling) theorem.